# How to loop through an array of objects, loop through each object and push each object into separate arrays for ngFor looping in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, angular7

I am working on an Angular 7 project and I am dealing with an api that returns an array of (recipes)objects on search and I want to get the all ingredients from each object so I can loop through them, get only what I want because each (recipe)object varys from the other

I have tried looping through the initial array of objects and then looped through each individual object and getting only the available ingredients per (recipe)object but I do not know how to push them into separate arrays. Whenever I push, all ingredients from all the objects gets pushed into a single array.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipesService } from 'src/app/services/recipes.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-search',
templateUrl: './search.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
s: string;
ingArray: any[] = []
measurementsArr = []
nothingFound = false;
itemsFound = false;
searchedData: any[] = [];
searchresults: number;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service:RecipesService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
  this.s = params.s;
  console.log(this.s)
})
this.searchDB()
}

searchDB(){
this.service.searchRecipeDB(this.s).subscribe((res:any)=>{
  if(res.meals === null){
    this.nothingFound = true;
  }else{
    this.searchedData = res.meals
    console.log(this.searchedData)
    this.itemsFound = true;
    this.searchresults=this.searchedData.length;
    let resultsarray = this.searchedData
    for(let y of resultsarray){ 
      for(let obj in y){ 
        if(obj.includes('strIngredient')){ 
          if(y[obj]!=null){ 
            if(y[obj].length > 0){ 
              this.ingArray.push(y[obj])  
              console.log(this.ingArray) 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  })


}

}
```

I have been able to loop through and get each ingredients from each (recipe)object but have been unable to push them into separate arrays without having to define multiple arrays. Is there a way I can push all ingredients from a (recipe)object into a separate array without having other ingredients from other (recipes)object added? I do not want to define several arrays because I am working with an api and I do not know the expected search results all the time [search results showing an array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6IWU.png)

Comment: can you share the search result data structure or share a sample result in json format?

Comment: too long but can you check this link ->https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6IWU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let y of resultsarray){
     ingrSub: Array<any> = new Array();
      for(let obj in y){ 
        if(obj.includes('strIngredient')){ 
          if(y[obj]!=null){ 
            if(y[obj].length > 0){ 
              ingrSub.push(y[obj])  
              console.log(this.ingArray) 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    if(ingrSub.length > 0)
          this.ingArray.push(ingrSub)
    else
       ingrSub = null;//just to be sure that we do not leak the memory if engine thinks the oposite in some case

    }
```

Comment: thanks but using an ngfor still displays all the ingredients and not each recipe's ingredient

Comment: but please can you explain what `ingrSub: Array<any> = new Array()` does?

Comment: Sure, it declares new local array object, but not as a class member. Then you fill out this array with your values and add the ref of this array to class member array.

Answer (score 0):

Just push obj, not y[obj]. Probably, I do not understand the task. And use of instead of in. Or do you wanna get some ingredient substrings from object?

Comment: pushing obj instead of y[obj] does the same thing. I am trying to push all ingredients for recipe A into an array and then push all ingredients of recipe B into an array too without having to declare two separate arrays

Comment: Okay, where do you create the second array in your code? You push every recipe to one class member. About which second array are you talking about?

Comment: I have just one array because I am working with an api and I do not know how many objects each search will bring so I was wondering if I can keep using that same array over and over again

Comment: How about two dimension array or map? Each successful search will add a sub array of your data to the class array

Comment: please how do I have go about that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    this.array_a = [] <- this add your array

this.array_b.forEach(array_b_item => {
  array_b_item.new_variable = JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(this.array_a)
  ); 
});

you can add values indivualy to array_b
```